# Is there a sample using DevExpress to have a TreeView as the drop-down of a combo edit?

Tags: devexpress

I need to place a DevExpress combo edit where the drop-down is a TreeView. DevExpress has a bunch of partial explinations of this, but no complete source. Anyone have a sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to use a PopupContainerEdit control. To do this you also create a PopupContainerControl, put a TreeView in the PopupContainerControl (set to fill size) and then have the PopupContainerEdit.Popup point to the PopupContainerControl.

Full source at [DevExpress combo box with a TreeView dropdown](http://blogs.windwardreports.com/davidt/2010/12/devexpress-combo-box-with-a-treeview-dropdown.html)